# Querying with Django to Database Json

Tags: python, sql, json, django, mongodb

I'm currently using Django as the backend of my website and a RESTapi. I've got two models Courses and Lectures and each Course has a few lectures. I am trying to get only the lectures related to a specific course.

After running manage.py runserver, is there a way to query the database from within the UI like in mongodb and cloudant?

Thanks!

Edited to include:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can run `python manage.py shell` to launch an interactive python interpreter. You will be able to import your models, request your database, etc...

1. Start your database server
2. Run `python manage.py shell`
3. Play :)

Check this tutorials to learn how to play with the API :

- [Django - Playing with the API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api)
- [Django-Rest-Framework - Working with Serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#working-with-serializers)

If you want to use **HTTP requests**, then :

1. Launch your Django server
2. Start your database
3. Import a HTTP Library like [request](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/) with `import requests`
4. Send HTTP request to your Django server

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I understand. Don't I need to host it on a url and then retrieve the json from there?

Comment: Do you want to use HTTP requests?

Comment: Yes. Currently I've got a Lecture with a Foreign Key constraint Course. It makes it very difficult to retrieve information since the "course" attr is a url and not a "title" or anything. I will update OP with an image to describe it.

Comment: Do you use Django-Rest-Framework to serialize and deserialize data?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using django-rest-framework

Comment: I have updated my answer with great tutorials to learn how to play with your models and serializers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95812/discussion-between-louis-barranqueiro-and-tryingtolearn).